# Javascript - chatbot

Tags: javascript, chatbot

I've been using the following in a pattern matching chatbot for years. A person types in an input box and the chatbot responds in an output box.

It's just a series of "if statements" and this is just one small part of it.

If someone types "yes" the bot responds with the following except on message 4 where I ask a question. Once that question is asked it will no longer trigger which is what I want.

I don't want that question to be asked over and over. This all worked until recently. I can't figure out why it no longer works.

```
var yes_q4_asked="false";

if (input.search("yes")!= -1) {  
message[0] = "ok, yes it is."; 
message[1] = "yes, I suppose so."; 
message[2] = "ok, I understand."; 
message[3] = "ok, I guess so."; 
message[4] = "yeah, I reckon so. Say what color are your eyes?"; 
message[5] = "yes, I thought as much."; 
num = [Math.floor(Math.random()*6)]
if ((num==4) && (yes_q4_asked=="false"))
{ 
yes_q4_asked=="true";
document.result.result.value = message[num];
return true;
}
while (num==4)
{
num = [Math.floor(Math.random()*6)]
}
document.result.result.value = message[num]; 
return true;}
```

Comment: If anyone else is interested in JavaScript chatbots, try [Eliza](http://www.masswerk.at/elizabot/)

Answer (score 3):

Someone has found my problem.
This line in the above code:

```
yes_q4_asked=="true";
```

Should be:

```
yes_q4_asked="true";
```

`one =` not `two ==`

Answer (score 0):

- `document.result.result.`are you sure that this is correct?
- `var yes_q4_asked="false";` why don't you use boolean values?

Comment: The actual bot is huge. I'm not looking to re-write it. I just hit a snag with this part.

Here is a demo that I use for testing if that helps anyone to get a better idea of how it works.

http://www.daniellechuchran.com/aademo.html In short if you type in "yes" it is going to reply with what you see in the example.                                                            
However if message 4 is triggered I don't want it to trigger again. Only once...no more. How can I do that. I want the other "yes" replies to continue as is.

Answer (score 0):

try linking your html to

```
<script src="https://webtinq.nl/assistent/js/script.js"></script>
```

, it's a fully working chatbot made with javascript, and it works like this:

```
alert(ask("hello"));
```

, and it will return

```
hello, how can i help you?
```

or

```
hi, how can i help you today?
```

and it uses some functions you can use in your own script too, like:

```
site("https://example.com");
```

, it will open a confirm popup and it will send you to the site, and:

```
or("hello", "hi");
```

, this function will return "hello" or, "hi", 50% change.
you can use

```
randomIntFromInterval(1, 10);
```

too, it will return a random number between 1 (included) and 10 (included).
it has a swear word detector, and after 10 swear words it will ban you. (using localstorage so use function

```
localStorage.clear();
```

or

```
localStorage.setItem("banned", "no");
```

and reload the page to unban)